# Get item in array that is not in object value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

How can I get the item 'legumes'?

This is what i tryed:

```js
let arr = ['cafe', 'fruit', 'legumes']

let objs = [
    {name: 'cafe'},
    {name: 'fruit'}
]

let result = arr.filter(x => objs.map(y => x != y.name));
console.log(result)

/*
expected result = ['legumes']
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

> let result = arr.filter(x => **objs.map(y => x != y.name)**);

Pls note that [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) will return an array instead.

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

**Solution:**
You should define the condition to return `true` or `false` inside.
As a result, you can use `every` or `includes` like below:

```js
let arr = ['cafe', 'fruit', 'legumes']

let objs = [
    {name: 'cafe'},
    {name: 'fruit'}
];
console.log(arr.filter(x => objs.every(obj => obj.name !== x)));

// more ways here
console.log(arr.filter(x => objs.filter(y => x != y.name).length > 1));
console.log(arr.filter(x => !objs.map(r => r.name).includes(x)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, i appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = ['cafe', 'fruit', 'legumes']

let objs = [
    {name: 'cafe'},
    {name: 'fruit'}
]

const values = objs.map(y => y.name)
let result = arr.filter(x => !values.includes(x));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ['cafe', 'fruit', 'legumes']

let objs = [
    {name: 'cafe'},
    {name: 'fruit'}
]

let result = arr.filter(x => {
  const values = objs.map(y => y.name)
  return !values.includes(x);
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = ['cafe', 'fruit', 'legumes']

let objs = [
    {name: 'cafe'},
    {name: 'fruit'}
]

let result = arr.filter(x => objs.every(obj => obj.name !== x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
    let arr = ['cafe', 'fruit', 'legumes']

let objs = [
    {name: 'cafe'},
    {name: 'fruit'}
]

let result = arr.filter(x => objs.map(y => y.name).indexOf(x) == -1);

console.log(result)
```